# How to pre fill the values in form fields which are already in database and deliver the partial form or taking the remaining inputs

Tags: django

i want to make a form in which the database is queryed and prefill the fields which are already been present to that model instance id or pk.

models.py

```
  class Uploads(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
        age = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
        gstin = models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=False,default='xxxxxxxxxx00000')
        PAN = models.CharField(max_length=10,default="xxxxxxxxxx",blank=False)
        doc_pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='static/files',blank=True)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/images',blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

forms.py  [  do i have to use super().clean() in clean method?, bcoz without using super() is also working , whats the use of super() ]

```
class Uploadform(forms.ModelForm):

   class Meta:
        model = Uploads
        fields ='__all__'

   def clean_gstin(self):
        gstin = self.cleaned_data.get('gstin')
        print(gstin)
        if len(gstin) != 15:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Input correct length of GSTIN')
        if gstin[:2].isdigit() == False:
            raise forms.ValidationError('put the 1st two digits as number')
        return gstin

   def clean_PAN(self):
       PAN = self.cleaned_data.get('PAN')
       if len(PAN) != 10:
           raise forms.ValidationError('input correct length')
       return PAN

   def clean(self):
       gst = self.cleaned_data.get('gstin')
       pan = self.cleaned_data.get('PAN')
       print(pan)
       print(gst)
       if not pan in gst:
           raise forms.ValidationError('worng GSTIN')
```

views.py

```
   def uploadview_django(request , id):
       x= Uploads.objects.all.filter(pk = id)
       if x:
          gst = x.gstin
          pan = x.pan
       if request.method == 'POST':
          form = Uploadform(request.POST , request.FILES)
          if form.is_valid():
               form.save()

               return redirect('index')
        else:

            form = Uploadform(gstin = gst , PAN = pan)

        return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
```

after suggestion done this:

```
   def uploadview_django(request):
    try:
       x = Uploads.objects.all().filter(pk = 12)
    except Uploads.DoesNotExists:
       x= None

    if request.method == 'POST':
         form = Uploadform(request.POST , request.FILES , instance=x)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()

           return redirect('index')
     else:
         form = Uploadform(instance=x)

     return render(request,'form.html',{'form':form})
```

showing error:

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\J A X\Anaconda3\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\J A X\Anaconda3\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\J A X\Anaconda3\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\J A X\Desktop\Django\practice\Appone\views.py" in uploadview_django
  27.         form = Uploadform(instance=x)

File "C:\Users\J A X\Anaconda3\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in **init**
  292.             object_data = model_to_dict(instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)

File "C:\Users\J A X\Anaconda3\envs\madeenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in model_to_dict
  82.     opts = instance._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at /form_django
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must query using get `x= Uploads.objects.all.get(pk = id)` , make sure to put this in a try except block, like this

```
try:
    x= Uploads.objects.get(pk = id)
except:
    x=None
```

Simple just pass the instance in the form's post and get methods, like this `form = Uploadform(request.POST , request.FILES, instance=x)` and `form = Uploadform(instance=x)`.

Now it should fill the fields values for which instance is given.

For an example from the docs look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Comment: what will i type in except block?

Comment: if there is a instance and there is value it will take it, else nothing will get populated

Comment: its showing and error :'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'

Comment: @Jax.ajay it should be `x= Uploads.objects.get(pk = id)` not .all.get inside try, sorry

Comment: how can i do this instance in forms.FORM not the modelform?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the `instance` while initialising the form like below

```
x = Uploads.objects.all.filter(pk=id)
# .... your code....
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Uploadform(instance=x, request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('index')
else:
    form = Uploadform(instance=x)
# .... your code....
```